Phonetic/ phonological, not orthographic, syllables of تَطْوِيْل?
Pronunciation of تَطْوِيْل (as verbal noun), is it 'tat-weel', or rather 'ta-tweel' ?
Notice the difference in syllable structure.

Does Arabic [otherwise] allow the consonant blend 'tw' at the beginning of syllables?

My Arabic is rusty but you can read the Wikipedia section which says there's only ever one consonant at the start of a syllable.

Which definition of 'consonant' is used here ? Some sources argue w=u̯, thus w is phonetically a vowel. 'consonant' may also refer to the status of a sound in a particular syllable. That's more phonological a term, according to which w is a consonant.

In summary, two homonyms may be relevant here, 'consonant' in a strictly phonetic sense, and syllable‑theoretic 'consonant'.
